# How do I use HideCustomAction to remove the "Site Contents" link from Quick Launch in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I've created a feature which should (according to numerous articles) remove the "Site Contents" link from the Quick Launch.

One problem:  This doesn't happen.

Here's what is in my elements.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">

  <HideCustomAction
    Id="HideSiteContents"
    GroupId="SiteActions"
    HideActionId="MenuItem_ViewAllSiteContents"
    Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu">
  </HideCustomAction>

  <CustomAction Id="SiteActionsToolBar" GroupId="SiteActions" Location="Microsoft.SharePoint.StandardMenu" Sequence="1000" Title="Added test button">
    <UrlAction Url="javascript:alert('Button was added and working');" />
  </CustomAction>
</Elements>
```

The test button is added to the site settings menu (Showing that the file is read and working) but I can't remove the Site Contents link like this.

Given the constraints I am under, doing this via a feature is the only acceptable solution - I could of course do it by some other means but that won't result in a workable solution.

Comment: So, loading a custom Css into the master page is not an appropriate way?

Comment: Unfortunately not.  I have been asked to do it specifically like this.   I just can't make it work, although it looks like it should.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is you are deploying this as a sandbox solution?

HideCustomAction needs to be deployed as a farm solution.